# CTRL+C quits wrong application

Tags: bash, shell-script

I just created my first bash script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/jhn/src/eth/ten
atom .
npm start
```

This does what it should, it opens atom in correct folder and starts the server. But when I want to stop the server in terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> it also kills atom. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> here kills your script. All the children get a signal, and they react to the signal that their parent is dying.

You might try `nohup` for `atom`

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/jhn/src/eth/ten
nohup atom . &
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `atom` is started in the current script of the current shell. Start it as a daemon - if that option is available - or run it in background, eventually with the `nohup` command, or `disown` it afterwards.